# Tool to convert java to c# code

Tags: java, c#, code-translation

What is the best tool out there at the moment to convert java to c#? Apart from

- j2ctranslator
- j#

I use IKVM at the moment.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where can I find a Java to C# converter?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/443010/where-can-i-find-a-java-to-c-converter)

Comment: I do not agree with off-topic, as It's clear viewing statistics ... shame :)

Comment: Found the following online Java to C# converter useful - https://www.javainuse.com/java2csharp

Answer (score 25):

For your reference:

- [Sharpen](http://developer.db4o.com/Projects/html/projectspaces/db4o_product_design/sharpen.html) by [db4o](http://db4o.com/)
- [XES](http://www.euclideanspace.com/software/language/xes/userGuide/convert/javaToCSharp/index.htm)
- [RemoteSoft Octopus](http://www.remotesoft.com/octopus/) (commercial)

Note: I had no experience on them.

Comment: id love to hear some feedback from someone who has tried XES... It looks like it would be far too simple to handle complex conversions.

Comment: also - I was not able to figure out how to use sharpen...

Comment: Spent 2 days trying to get Sharpen to build and run, but it is an Eclipse plugin, so the task proved impossible, mostly due to Eclipse being the worst piece of software ever written in the history of the universe. And yes, I tried the XobotOS version, also broken. Tried XES, but the process is so slow and complicated that it would actually be faster to re-write by hand and Remotesoft Octopus is still in beta testing phase.

Comment: It looks like sharpen is still active but at a different location? https://github.com/slluis/sharpen the only official location I found is this ugly svn http://source.db4o.com/db4o/trunk/sharpen/

Comment: I'm intrigued by the relatively high votes on this question compared to the comments, which basically say each option is not effective. Would love to hear from the upvoters or anybody who can recommend anything effective as a converter

Comment: Sharpen is dead

Answer (score 12):

Don't. Leave them as Java and use IKVM to convert them to .Net DLLs.

- http://www.ikvm.net/devguide/java2net.html
- http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/ikvm/index.php?title=Ikvmc

Comment: Ikvm throws an error when we initialize calender library :(

Comment: The IKVM project lead has announced that he has decided to stop working on IKVM.NET and hopes that someone else will fork it (http://weblog.ikvm.net/2017/04/21/TheEndOfIKVMNET.aspx)

Answer (score 9):

I've had good results with this one.  Much easier to use than Sharpen.

http://tangiblesoftwaresolutions.com/Product_Details/Java_to_CSharp_Converter.html

Comment: I have used this. And it really worked great for me.

Answer (score 6):

Microsoft has a tool called JLCA: [Java Language Conversion Assistant](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=46bea47e-d47f-4349-9b4f-904b0a973174&displaylang=en). I can't tell if it is better though, as I have never compared the two.

Comment: Ya I've tried that before and it doesn't really work very well. I think Microsoft has stopped support for it. It doesn't support newer java features like generics.

Comment: Visual Studio 2003 appears to be required to install

Comment: @BozoJoe [It's supported on 2005 as well](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/7tatw8a2%28v=vs.80%29.aspx). But yeah, screw that.

Comment: JLCA was not supported after VS 2005

Comment: JLCA link is dead

Comment: still works for me. you just get a stupid big Surface Pro ad on top of the page :)