# Convert java to c# .net

Tags: c#, java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Tool to convert java to c# code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/896867/tool-to-convert-java-to-c-code)

I have done a project in java and I want to convert it to C#.Net. I'm using Visual Studio 2008. How can I convert the code from Java to C#? Are there any tools available?

Comment: Duplicate question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/896867/tool-to-convert-java-to-c-code

Comment: Seems a shame to close this since it has more answers than the original.  I'll come back and merge them later so these answers will live on.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are tools that can help do this. For example this one from the team who created db4o:

[Smart java to c# conversion for the masses with sharpen](http://developer.db4o.com/blogs/product_news/archive/2008/05/20/smart-java-to-c-conversion-for-the-masses-with-sharpen.aspx)

Note that these are not perfect and some constructs and API's cannot be easily translated.

Answer (score 2):

[IKVM.NET Bytecode Compiler](http://www.ikvm.net/userguide/ikvmc.html)

Answer (score 1):

I think your best shot would be, unless you **really really** need all the code in C#, to use [Visual J#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vjsharp/default.aspx) and integrate your Java code with C#.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an [Msdn Article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c6t6bsdk(VS.80).aspx) about converting from Java to Visual C#.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft used to support their own .net implementation of the Java language, called Java#, but unfortunetelly they discontinued the project.

But at least you could try it to see if it could help you to convert your code to .net

Comment: J#. Only implemented a Microsoft "embrace, extend and extinguish" version of Java 1.1 (Java 1.1 was superseded by Java 2 in 1998).