# Is there a plugin for copy Java code and paste as C# code?

Tags: c#, java

I am looking for a decent tool to convert Java to C#. I have a few hundreds of lines that I need to move to C#.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Tool to convert java to c# code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/896867/tool-to-convert-java-to-c-code)

Comment: If it's just a few hundred and not thousands of lines of code, it might make sense to reimplement/refactor the code in C#. Though the languages are quite similar syntactally, the underlying framework has differences where you may be able to improve perf, reliability, or even readability by targetting the CLR specifically.

Comment: The main problem is not the difference in languages. The code itself will compile with only a few manual fixes. It's the difference in the class library they are built on. Do you really want to add a dependency on some reimplementation of java libraries? Some bigger projects do that, but for a small project I'd just copy&paste and then fix manually substituting .net types where appropriate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.eggheadcafe.com/software/aspnet/31371991/conversion-from-java-to-c-in-visual-studio-2008.aspx. have a look.