# To make development portable to Java, does it make sense to do the whole development on J# vs C#?

Tags: c#, j#

To make development portable to Java, does it make sense to do the whole development on J# vs C#? What happens to missing bits in Java that exist in C# like lambda expression and so on?

What is the best way to achieve portability?

Comment: If you target is Java why not start there? (.NET and Java are very different in many respects – despite the use of curly braces – and portability would require a common subset, that doesn't exist, of the framework.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I definitely *wouldn't* use J# - it's not supported any more, and it only supported Java 1.1.4 anyway, IIRC.

I would personally recommend keeping the *overall architecture* consistent between the two languages, but then write the code separately, manually, taking into account the different idioms in the different languages.

If your codebase uses data-driven tests, it would be good to share that data between the two languages, as a way of helping to ensure data portability.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you don't use J# anymore as it has been discontinued. The last version has been shipped with Visual Studio 2005.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to J#-specific *language* extensions and .NET CLR support, its [runtime library](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=4712) implements Java 2 Collections Framework (without the `java.util.concurrent` extensions, though) and even some JFC/Swing, via the [Supplemental UI Library](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k12dt1e0%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

So you'll be limited to the Java 1.4 API.

Given that J# has been discontinued long ago, I wouldn't suggest you invest your time into it.

If you really need portability between JVM and CLR, I'd take a look at [IKVM](https://www.ikvm.net/) (implements Java 1.7 API on top of CLR), [Scala for .NET](http://www.scala-lang.org/old/node/168) (discontinued circa Scala 2.10) or languages like *Ruby* ([JRuby](http://jruby.org/)/[IronRuby](http://ironruby.net/)) or *Python* ([Jython](http://www.jython.org/)/[IronPython](http://ironpython.net/)).

Alternatively, you can *generate* your C# for .NET -- there're Java to C# [converters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2014620/1343979) [available](https://www.tangiblesoftwaresolutions.com/product_details/java_to_csharp_converter.html).