# Conversion from POJO to POCO

Tags: c#, java, compact-framework, poco, pojo

I'm creating a Compact Framework 3.5 application, which is the client side of an older Java webapp. The communication protocol between both sides is REST+JSON.

Serialization of the POJOs to JSON is not a matter since the POJOs already exist.
But instead of rewriting from scratch a C# version of all the POJOs sources to be able to deserialize the JSON client-side, I would prefer a generation using some tools. 
Or at least, do the conversion manually with a "standardized" method.

Do you know some tools that would match these needs ? Or some manual method ?

Thanks by advance

Fabien

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it really depends on what you have

1. If you have a [WADL](http://wadl.java.net/) than there are probably tools that can generate classes from it.
2. If you have XSD's of the request and response objects you can also generate C# classes from it.
3. [You can try using tools that convert java to C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/896867/tool-to-convert-java-to-c-sharp-code)

Comment: OKay, I used JDK's schemagen.exe and MSDK's xsd.exe to do the job, using XSD as buffer. Thank You.