# Java to C# converter.

Tags: java, c#-3.0

What is the standard Java to C# converter?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Where can I find a Java to C# converter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/443010/where-can-i-find-a-java-to-c-sharp-converter)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try [Sharpen](http://developer.db4o.com/Resources/view.aspx/Reference/Sharpen).

Comment: Do you have any experience with this?  Does it really work or it only a weak translation?