# Java Preprocessor in C#

Tags: c#, java, regex, preprocessor

Say I want to create a sort of Pre-processor for existing java code, so I can get the language specific keywords and objects, and then create routines that convert them to their Csharp equivalents, using Csharp code - what route should this take? I'm thinking of Regular Expressions, but I'm fuzzed.

I have a bunch of about a 100 .java files and I need to convert them to csharp code in record time. I have manually done just about five of them and I have serious headaches already.

Or are there any tools out there that already do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may take a look at [ikvmc](http://www.ikvm.net/userguide/ikvmc.html). It takes a `.class` or `.jar` file and spits a managed .NET assembly which has reference to a couple of other assemblies. I've used it personally for including functionality from JAVA libraries that didn't have a .NET port.

If you want to migrate the source code than only by doing it manually you will have quality result. Automated code conversion tools could only translate the syntax but cannot take advantage of some specific features that different frameworks can offer.

Answer (score 2):

You can try the [JLCA](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=46bea47e-d47f-4349-9b4f-904b0a973174&displaylang=en) (Java Language Converting Assistant)

Answer (score 0):

[Where can I find a Java to C# converter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/443010/where-can-i-find-a-java-to-c-converter)

Comment: Should have been a comment or close vote, imho.