# Where is the Java Language Conversion Assistant (JLCA) 3.0?

Tags: c#, java

Microsoft supposedly offer(ed?) something called the JLCA, which converts Java into C#. I can't find any download or anything for it. Does anyone have any information about this tool and how to use it in VS2008/2010? I can find version 2.0 but not 3.0... supposedly it came built into VS2005?

Comment: This has absolutely nothing to do with J#. That tag doesn't belong here.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Microsoft Java Language Conversion Assistant 3.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vjsharp/aa718346.aspx)

Page has been moved to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/troubleshoot/visualstudio/language-compilers/jlca-available-download but download doesn't seem to be available any more.

Anyway, it's [discontinued](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vjsharp/default.aspx):

> Retirement of J# language and Java
> Language Conversion Assistant from
> future versions of Visual Studio
>
> Since customers have told us that the
> existing J# feature set largely meets
> their needs and usage of J# is
> declining, Microsoft is retiring the
> Visual J# product and Java Language
> Conversion Assistant tool to better
> allocate resources for other customer
> requirements. The J# language and JLCA
> tool will not be available in future
> versions of Visual Studio. To preserve
> existing customer investments in J#,
> Microsoft will continue to support the
> J# and JLCA technology that shipped
> with Visual Studio 2005 through to
> 2015 as per our product life-cycle
> strategy.

Comment: appears the link has gone cold as well. Sheesh MS, at least let us download it.

Comment: Albeit dated, discontinued, this link appears to be working: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/819018

Comment: Year 2023 update.  "https://www.microsoft.com/download/details.aspx?id=14349" -> We're sorry, this download is no longer available.