# Are there any tools to convert Java to C#?

Tags: c#, java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where can I find a Java to C# converter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/443010/where-can-i-find-a-java-to-c-converter)

Are there any free converters or tools that can convert java projects to C#? I have java code and I want to convert it to C#.

Comment: They are called programmers, and they are not free...

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/896867/tool-to-convert-java-to-c-code

Comment: Copy of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/443010/where-can-i-find-a-java-to-c-converter ?

Answer (score 5):

From Microsoft, have a look. [The Java Language Conversion Assistant (JLCA)](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/819018)

Comment: I guess it is - you can download from... http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyId=46BEA47E-D47F-4349-9B4F-904B0A973174&displaylang=en

Answer (score 3):

There might be something that claims it can do it, but I would not trust it. This is a significant port and it takes a programmer to make sure it happens correctly.

Comment: Mmmmmmmmm, Agreed But u know how hard would it be to re-write the code and keep all the logic same :(

Comment: @Madiha: Are you expecting the C# code to be maintainable?

Comment: Well, what i need is just conversion. I am not even thinking about accurate or exact running code.

Comment: @Madiha - yes, we do. That's why it can't be done automatically. Suck it up and hire a programmer.

Comment: AAAAHhhh Means i can't get it done automatically :-s

Answer (score 2):

I've used [JNBridge](http://www.jnbridge.com/) in the past on some small to medium projects with success.  This allows you to call a Java library from .NET and vice versa.  If you are dealing with relatively simple types in your interfaces, it might be a good way to go.

Answer (score 1):

```
Process.Start("java MyClass.java");
```

Comment: Won't run. You need to compile the Java class first ;)

Comment: Hey, it sounds working can u explain a bit more ? ? ?

Comment: @Madiha: This answer was intended to be a joke.  Although, it would be nice to know WHY you need the conversion?  If you seriously just need to run the code from an ASP.Net front-end, then I suppose you could actually do this...

Comment: Actually i want to migrate my application from java to .net, but currently i m trying with some small code file so that i could get an idea how fine the conversion could be . . .

Answer (score 1):

There is Sharpen, but I was unable to setup it properly
http://developer.db4o.com/Projects/html/projectspaces/db4o_product_design/sharpen.html

Answer (score 1):

If you just want it to *RUN* but not necessarily be converted to C# source code, you might find http://www.ikvm.net/ an interesting alternative.

It provides the facilities to run Java code on the .NET-runtime.