# ArrayList<Uri> Intent. How to write in C#

Tags: c#

How to write this in C#?

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ActionSendMultiple, Android.Provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.ExternalContentUri);
handler(intent);
```

....

```
void handler(Intent intent)
{
    ArrayList<Uri> imageUris = intent.GetParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.ExtraStream);

    ...
}
```

Comment: `ArrayList` is still avaiable in C# but it belongs on old days when C# doesn't have _generics_. Use `List<T>` instead.

Comment: It returns IList, read documentation http://docs.go-mono.com/index.aspx?link=M%3AAndroid.Content.Intent.GetIntegerArrayListExtra(System.String)

Comment: I'm sure you're not actually going to ask questions as you progress line by line. Short answer: Use the `List<T>` class (which is not an interface in the C# BCL as opposed to Java's). Long answer: please read the rules of this site... Better answer: I'm sure there exist Java 2 C# translators which work empirically of course, but they could give you a hand. Look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/443010/where-can-i-find-a-java-to-c-sharp-converter

Comment: I edited my question, I want it to match the Intent for Android. But the code is written in Java, so now I want to change it to C#

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ArrayList` is available is c# but it does not have a generic (`<T>`) form. `ArrayList` is a list of objects.

What you want is `System.Collections.Generic.List<T>`

EDIT : In response to comments, try this;

```
List<Uri> imageUris = new List<Uri>(intent.GetIntegerArrayListExtra(Intent.ExtraStream));
```

Comment: more pragmatic comment, why not to use `IList<Uri>`?

Comment: Good question. I always shoot for List<T> as it has more methods on it.

Comment: sorry, It should be intent.GetParcelableArrayListExtra, but when i follow your method, i get error.

Comment: `it has more methods on it` just because it is a specific implementation, not the abstraction. Following the principle of dependency inversion, one should rely on concrete implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Easy, just use `List<Uri>`. It's also faster than ArrayList.