# Convert Java code to equalent C# for below lines

Tags: java, c#

Hi I have to convert my project from java to C# and i need help with below lines to convert them into c#. Please look at below image and code which i have typed here.

```
 for (String profile : userProfiles)

    {
        int maxuser = 100;
        if (profile.equals("astd"))
            maxuser = 300;

        for (String suffix : suffixes)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i <= maxuser; i++)
            {

                String prefix = profile;
                System.out.println("prefix" + prefix);
                String num = Integer.toString(i);
                if (num.length() < 2)
                    num = "0" + num;
                String postfix = num;

                String username = prefix + postfix + suffix;
                System.out.println(username);

                //TODO add a

                Gson gson = new Gson();
                User u = new User();
                u.setFirstName(username
```

[image]

Comment: Read about ForEach loop

Comment: Did You Try something that didn't work? Have you written any c# code to tackle this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not only foreach; there are lot more difference in the given code, i will specify some of them here:

1. [String and string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7074/whats-the-difference-between-string-and-string) are different in c#
2. use [foreach](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ttw7t8t6.aspx) instead for `for(:)`
3. use  [Console.WriteLine()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/system.console.writeline(v=vs.110).aspx) to print
4. for converstion use `.ToString()` instead for `Integer.toString`

Here is the corrected code

```
foreach (string profile in userProfiles)
        {
            int maxuser = 100;
            if (profile.Equals("astd"))
                maxuser = 300;
            foreach (string suffix in suffixes)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i <= maxuser; i++)
                {
                    string prefix = profile;
                    Console.WriteLine("prefix" + prefix);
                    string num = i.ToString();
                    if (num.Length < 2)
                        num = "0" + num;
                    string postfix = num;
                    string username = prefix + postfix + suffix;
                    Console.WriteLine(username);
                    //TODO add a
                    Gson gson = new Gson();
                    User u = new User();
                    u.setFirstName(username);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: spoon fed....IMHO, we should not encourage such questions....We should try to guide OP first to try out on his own..

Comment: that's why i have included reference links in the answer. And i believe this is not a tuition class to give step by step guidelines

Comment: But you have done opposite of what you are saying...OP has complete code which he can copy paste and done.

Comment: I understand it is not tuition but again it is not code writing service...There should be some effort from OP first

Comment: So what you are trying to say? not need to provide answer only provide guidelines, isn't it?

Comment: you have complete right to provide direct answers or answers with guidelines or only guidelines...but for sake of community, Ideal would be asking OP to try first and then working on what OP has tried...

Answer (score 1):

**Equivalents:**

*Java*

```
for (String profile : userProfiles)
```

*C#*

```
foreach (string profile in userprofiles)
```

---

*Java*

```
System.out.println("text");
```

*C#*

```
Console.WriteLine("text");
```

---

*Java*

```
Integer.toString(i);
```

*C#*

```
i.ToString();
```

---

*Java*

```
num.length()
```

*C#*

```
num.Length
```

Answer (score 0):

From this: `for (String profile : userProfiles)`

to this: `foreach(String profile in userProfiles)`

From this:

```
if (profile.equals("astd"))
     maxuser = 300;
```

To this:

```
if(profile == "astd")
   maxuser=300;
```

From this: `System.out.println("prefix" + prefix);`

To this: `Console.WriteLine("prefix" + prefix); //assuming you're doing a console app`

Lastly your `num.length()` should just be `num.length`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the tools available,although it is better to do it manually.
So you use tools to get the syntax right atleast

Here are some reference

[Where can I find a Java to C# converter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/443010/where-can-i-find-a-java-to-c-sharp-converter)

[How should I convert Java code to C# code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/168837/how-should-i-convert-java-code-to-c-sharp-code?lq=1)